# Alert / notification in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, download, notifications, alert

I would like to have an alert / notification in shiny app, when user click on download button !
All the examples just work if you have an action button like :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)
 
ui <- fluidPage(
   useShinyalert(),  # Set up shinyalert
   actionButton("preview", "Preview")
 )
 
 server <- function(input, output, session) {
   observeEvent(input$preview, {
     # Show a modal when the button is pressed
     shinyalert("Oops!", "Something went wrong.", type = "error")
   })
 }
 
 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want to design similar concept for download button and if we have a download button, then there is no `input$preview` because I assume for `downloadButton` we have `output$preview` and that does not work with current setup !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for a more comprehensive example of how you can use this popup to confirm the download, you can do the following:

1. We create another actionbutton based on examples [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-stop-download-in-downloadhandler/8268/3)
2. We are going to hide the original `downloadButton` using the `style = "visibility: hidden;"`
3. We shall listen to the download event via `document.getElementById('downloadData').click();`
4. We are going to create a  `reactiveValues` variable to see if the users want to download the data or not
5. Finally, we need to reset the response so you can click on the `Ok` button in the popup continuously, otherwise it will not trigger again as it is set to `TRUE`

---

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    useShinyalert(), 
    actionButton("init", "Download", icon = icon("download")),
    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download", style = "visibility: hidden;")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    global <- reactiveValues(response = FALSE)
    
    observeEvent(input$init,{
        shinyalert("Confirmation", 
                   "Do you want to download the data?", 
                   type = "success",
                   callbackR = function(x) {
                       global$response <- x
                   },
                   showCancelButton = TRUE
        )
    })
    
    observeEvent(global$response,{
        if(global$response){
            shinyjs::runjs("document.getElementById('downloadData').click();")
            global$response <- FALSE
        }
    })
    
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(mtcars, file)
        }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]